# Unable to see contact in the whatsapp forward contact list

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am able to see a contact on the whatsapp contact list. But suddenly I am not able to see the contact in the forward contact list when I try to forward a message to the contact. What can possibly be the reason for this?